# RewriteRule giving me issues with my regex

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do a simple redirect where going to a url like `www.example.com/foo` will take me to `www.example.com/quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=foo`.

For testing purposes I started with this:

`RewriteRule ^(m.*)$ /quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=$1`

This works great for use cases where the foo starts with the letter: m, but I want it to be super customizable. So then I make this my redirect (note the removal of the letter m):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=$1`

Why isn't the RewriteRule above not working for any instance of `foo`? I believe there's something wrong with my Regex?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=$1
> ```

Depending on what other directives you have in your `.htaccess` file, this is possibly causing an internal rewrite loop, which is preventing the URL from ever resolving correctly (do you get a 500 Internal Server Error?). Or, at best, an invalid rewrite to `/quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=quokka/inquiry/ask.php`.

*Aside:* Note that, as mentioned, this is an *internal rewrite*, not strictly a "redirect" as you stated in your question. The term "redirect" usually refers to an "external 3xx redirect". (Although admittedly the Apache docs also confuse these terms, but do at least qualify this as an "internal redirect".)

In the case of the above directive, the rewritten URL is also captured by the `^(.*)$` pattern (which captures *anything*), which results in a loop something like:

1. Request: `www.example.com/foo`
2. Rewritten to: `/quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=foo`
3. Rewritten to: `/quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=quokka/inquiry/ask.php`
4. Rewritten to: `/quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=quokka/inquiry/ask.php`
5. :

URL-rewriting does not stop when it gets to the end of the `.htaccess` file. Processing loops until the URL passes through unchanged. (Although what is considered a "change" is not always entirely clear, as you can get loops simply by rewriting the URL, even when the rewritten URL is the same, as in step#4 above.)

The pattern `^(m.*)$` "works" because the rewritten URL does not start with an "m". But if you have an other URLs that start with an "m", then these will also be rewritten and become inaccessible.

You need to have a *unique* URL that only captures "user IDs" (in this case). For example, all URLs that reference "user IDs" could have a specific prefix, eg. `example.com/u/<userid>`.

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=$1
```

Or perhaps are of a maximum length that does not conflict with any other URL (eg. between 3 and 8 chars):

```
RewriteRule ^(.{3,8})$ /quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=$1
```

Also, if you are restrictive as possible on the format of the user ID then this might also be sufficient. eg. only lowercase letters:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=$1
```

However, using a prefix and restriction (regex should always be as *restrictive* as possible) would be my preference, as it avoids potential conflicts in the future. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^u/([a-z]{3,8})$ /quokka/inquiry/ask.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Also, include the `L` flag to ensure that no other directives that immediately follow are processed.

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer and also the guidance. I was able to resolve my error by adding the following to the RewriteRule: `^/ask(.*)$`